# Linked rows, single table SQL

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table with parts and different phases. `FromID=0` is where the material for the parts is entered. `part1` and `part2` are processed and then assembled to `part3`.

```
ID    Partname   FromID     Parts     Process
----------------------------------------------------
1     part1           0        10     process1 part1       
2     part1           1         0     process2 part1
3     part2           0        10     process1 part2
4     part2           1         0     process2 part2
5     part3           2         0     Assembly part1
6     part3           4         0     Assembly part2
```

Is there a way to write a query to get a part and all its subparts that can handle nested subparts as well? I'm using MS Access 2010 and C#.

The result should look like this

**PartName = part1**

```
ID    Partname   FromID     Parts     Work
-------------------------------------------
1     part1           0        10     work1 part1       
2     part1           1         0     work2 part1
```

**PartName = part2**

```
ID    Partname   FromID     Parts     Work
-------------------------------------------
3     part2           0        10     work1 part2
4     part2           1         0     work2 part2
```

**PartName = part3**

```
ID    Partname   FromID     Parts     Work
-------------------------------------------
1     part1           0        10     work1 part1       
2     part1           1         0     work2 part1
5     part3           2         0     Assembly part1
3     part2           0        10     work1 part2
4     part2           1         0     work2 part2
6     part3           4         0     Assembly part2
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Table1 
                LEFT JOIN Table1 AS Table2 ON Table2.FromID=Table1.ID
                WHERE (Table1.Part='Part3' Or Table2.Part='Part3')

Answer (score 0):

Use modified pre order tree traversal to mark the rows for quick querying.  Check out this write up:

http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2006/03/24/storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-database-part-2a-modified-preorder-tree-traversal/

If you are planning to deploy on SQL server you could consider using common table expressions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx